# Insert new data into table only if it differs from latest insert

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I want to add stock prices to a table - but only if buy or sell changed in compare to the last record.
Therefor UNIQUE does not really work since it doesn't allow the same price combo in the table more than once.
I can think of ways solving the issue outside of postgres (before actually inserting rows) but i was wondering if there is a way to **set up the prices table** handling this for me.

```
CREATE TABLE stock(
    id SMALLSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(3) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE prices(
    id SMALLSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT current_timestamp,
    stock_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    buy NUMERIC(15, 6) NOT NULL,
    sell NUMERIC(15, 6) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (stock_id) REFERENCES stock(id),
    UNIQUE(stock_id, buy, sell) 
);


INSERT INTO stock(name) VALUES('abc');
INSERT INTO prices (stock_id, buy, sell) VALUES (1, 1.5, 1.4) 
ON CONFLICT (stock_id, buy, sell) DO NOTHING;
INSERT INTO prices (stock_id, buy, sell) VALUES (1, 1.5, 1.4) 
ON CONFLICT (stock_id, buy, sell) DO NOTHING; -- this record should not be added to the table
INSERT INTO prices (stock_id, buy, sell) VALUES (1, 1.6, 1.5) 
ON CONFLICT (stock_id, buy, sell) DO NOTHING;
INSERT INTO prices (stock_id, buy, sell) VALUES (1, 1.5, 1.4) 
ON CONFLICT (stock_id, buy, sell) DO NOTHING; -- this one should be added to the table
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9396f/1)

So in my example i would like to have 3 rows in the table instead of 2 - only the 2nd insert into prices should be blocked, not the 4th one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you wrote, a unique constraint is not a suitable solution to the problem. A trigger is a natural approach in such cases, example:

```
create or replace function before_insert_on_prices()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
declare
    last_rec record;
begin
    select buy, sell
    from prices
    where stock_id = new.stock_id
    order by created_at desc
    limit 1
    into last_rec;

    if found and last_rec = (new.buy, new.sell) then
        return null;
    end if;
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger before_insert_on_prices
before insert on prices
for each row execute procedure before_insert_on_prices();
```

Note that the trigger will work well only when new rows are inserted in separate transactions, due to the fact that multiple rows inserted in a single transaction will have the same timestamp in `created_at`. However, this behaviour is quite logical and acceptable, I think.

[Working example in rextester.](http://rextester.com/IVFI3999)

Comment: As far as i understand you mean that i can only insert one new price pair per stock. So if i add the newest prices for lots of different stocks to the table that is no problem. Only if i would add two rows of prices for the same stock it could break, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The last note concerns a single `stock_id`.